# The only technical guy in an administrative service, interfacing with a dev team : how would you call this position?

Tags: position

Some years ago, I worked for a public institution, in a small team with specific (educational) activity. This team was mostly an administrative team, in which I was the only technical guy.

The team relied on an application developed by a third party dev team, and this application was used also by some other administrative teams like mine. My job was to specify our needs and to ensure that the application released by the dev team filled those needs, considering that this application had to fill the other administrative teams needs as well.

How would you call such a position ?

This is a weird question, but the fact is that my contract said "developer", which I clearly wasn't (except for some minor time frames when I actually wrote code).

It could be a product owner position, more or less, but the fact that some functionalities had to be negociated with other teams bothers me a little. What bothers me a little more is that we didn't follow any agile methodology at the time, making product owner label quite weird.

Any idea ?

Comment: "Technical liaison" is possible, "Product manager" or "Product owner"

Comment: Don't get hung up on methodologies.  I've yet to run into ANYONE who works a "pure" version of any methodology.  "Product manager" is what I'd call your role, especially since you coordinated external contractors/vendors.